# Integral of $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{-y^2/2} \sinh(cy)^2} {\cosh(Mcy) }dy$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, exponential-function, hyperbolic-functions

Is it difficult to compute or find a good computable lower bound on the integral
\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{-y^2/2} \sinh(cy)^2} {\cosh(Mcy) }dy
\end{align*}
where $c$ and $M$ are constants.

It's not hard to see that the integral is convergent but how should this be approached?

I feel like this integral has already been looked at?

Answer (score 3):

Notice that

$$ I = I(M,c) := \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-y^2/2}\sinh^2 (cy)}{\cosh(Mcy)} \, dy
= \frac{1}{c} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-y^2/2c^2}\sinh^2 y}{\cosh(My)} \, dy. $$

Then as $c \to \infty$ and $M > 2$,

$$ I \sim \frac{1}{c} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sinh^2 y}{\cosh(My)} \, dy = \frac{\pi}{2Mc}(\sec(\pi/M) - 1). $$

Comment: Could you explain ho you pooled the $c$ out of hyperbolic functions? Change of variable right?

Comment: Also, the answer to the second integral is it $\sec$ or $\sech$??

Comment: @Boby, That's right. It is change of variable. Also, $\sec$ is correct. For example, the integral diverges to $\infty$ as $M \to 2^+$, and this phenomenon is exactly replicated by the answer.

Comment: Could you point me a table where you got that integral? Also, do you think it is possible to give a good lower bound for any $c$?

Comment: Could you please give more details. For example why does $M>2$ and how did you do the last integral?